# Oracle HTML Logon Form _FORM_SUBMIT_BUTTON

Tags: oracle

I am having problems writing code to authenticate user with Oracle EBS.

```
form_id => "DefaultFormName",
fields => {
    usernameField => $username,
    passwordField => $password,
    '_FORM_SUBMIT_BUTTON' => "SubmitButtonhG2fwItG",
},
```

The cause of the failed logon boils down to the value passed for _FORM_SUBMIT_BUTTON. It seems this value takes the form of:

_FORM_SUBMIT_BUTTON = SubmitButton<8 digit dynamic string>

e.g.

_FORM_SUBMIT_BUTTON = SubmitButtonhG2fwItG

Any ideas how I can configure the Oracle EBS v12.1 to stop generating and requesting for the 8 digit dynamic string. I've not seen this dynamic string in other implementations with the same Oracle software stack and seems to vary between different Oracle EBS implementation depending on how it was installed and configured.

-Abdul